# CSS :nth-child() style every 2nd and 3rd for same color and so on

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I style my links in this order:

1st red, 2nd blue, 3rd blue, 4th red, 5th red, 6th blue, 7th blue and etc. There's the image example:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Ass per your question title the CSS `:nth-child` holds the key.

Comment: I tried various examples i.e. nth-child(3n+1) gives me #1 and #4 red color, but how do I do that #2 and #3 becomes blue?

Comment: `div {background-color: blue;}`

Comment: If you have attempted a solution so far it would be best to include that in your question! It seems to me that you have a pattern that repeats every `4n`... Simplest would be to write 4 nth-child rules

Comment: At the very least include the HTML that you're trying to apply styles to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
li:nth-child(4n+1),
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(4n+2),
li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! But isherwood workaround also worked. Can't believe I didn't come up with that one myself. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-child(4n), div:nth-child(4n+1) { background: red; }
div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) { background: blue; }
```

Here is jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WTRhz/